# Page refresh printing raw html code instead of output

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a chrome extension for my college website.Here is the small code:

```
setInterval(function(){ location.reload(); }, 600000);
```

This is the only piece of code I'm using for refreshing the page just to prevent session timeout.Its working quite well except this:
[image: This is the error picture.]

It is printing the raw html code sometimes in the left part and sometimes on the right part.What might be the reason for this and how can I overcome this ?

Comment: nothing can be understood from the question

Comment: It is showing raw code instead of rendered output

Comment: may be because cookies are getting expired